# Recoverable fatal error: Object of class SendGrid\Mail\Mail could not be converted to string

Tags: php, sendgrid

I am trying to pass a dynamic value using SendGrid's PHP Library. It works when I pass in a string but I add a dynamic value, I get this error
**Recoverable fatal error: Object of class SendGrid\Mail\Mail could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\vendor\sendgrid\sendgrid\lib\helper\Assert.php on line 30**

This one works

```
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
$email->setFrom("support@example.com", "example");
$email->setSubject("IMPORTANT: Signal failure");
$email->addTo("user@exampl.com", "{$fname}");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "{$message}");
$email->addContent(
    "text/html", "{$message}"
);
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid('APIKEY');
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
```

**This one fails**

```
 $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
    $email->setFrom("support@example.com", "example");
    $email->setSubject("IMPORTANT: Signal failure");
    $email->addTo("{$email}", "{$fname}"); //this line causes the error
    $email->addContent("text/plain", "{$message}");
    $email->addContent(
        "text/html", "{$message}"
    );
    $sendgrid = new \SendGrid('APIKEY');
    try {
        $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
        print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
        print_r($response->headers());
        print $response->body() . "\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
    }
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: because you're using same variable name. try to change the variable name inside the addTo()

Comment: `$email->addTo("{$email}", "{$fname}")` $email is not a string, it is the instance of `\SendGrid\Mail\Mail()` and seems not to have the Stringable implementation.

Comment: hard to believe, I've been struggling with that error for the past 3 days. thanks, it's working now

Comment: Better variable naming is the key. `$mailer = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();` or `$sendGridMail = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();` would be much better.

Comment: I'll do just that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example where it fails, `$email` is not a string containing an email address. It is an instance of `\SendGrid\Mail\Mail()`.

> Calling it as a string won't work, because it looks like `\SendGrid\Mail\Mail()` does not implement the [Stringable interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring).

You can prevent accidents like these by using better variable names like

```
$mailer = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
```

or

```
$sendGridMail = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
```